# what is the biggest frame size that I can set that would need 3 levels of paging in a page table with 64bit addressing?

Tags: memory, memory-management, virtual-memory, multi-level, page-tables

I am doing multilevel paging and my address space is 64 bits. I need to find the largest frame size I can that would require 3 levels of paging.

I do not understand how having a specific frame size would force me to have a set amount of levels in my page table.